# Windows: Get mouse pointer to go off screen ~ 1000px

Tags: c++, windows, virtual, drivers

I would like to allow the user to move the mouse pointer off the right side of the physical monitor for some distance (say 1000 pixels in each direction). Does anyone know how to do this in Windows?

I read in the [Windows API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145136%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that the size of the virtual screen is the maximum size of all monitors in each direction, with the primary monitor top-left corner at 0,0 ([see picture here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145136%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Is there anyway to override the size of the virtual screen? I think that would be the easiest way.

If not, should I use a fake display driver? Would I need one driver and two fake hardware instances (one for right side of the screen and other for left?

Comment: Just curious: why? How will you know you succeeded?

Comment: Right now, the mouse stops at the right side of the screen. so if I see the mouse pointer move off the screen I will know it worked. I can also read the side of the virtual desktop

Comment: But that still does not explain WHY you need this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a way to tell windows that the screen is bigger than it really is - that's what happens when yo have a dual monitor setup [well, the cursor can move to the second screen - but the actual coordinates are now outside the first screen, so the system supports this]. However, to move the cursor OUTSIDE OF THE drawing surface, probably not without tricking windows that there is more drawing surface than there really is...

Comment: I worked with graphics drivers and in particular mouse-cursor code, and I wrote some code to allow two monitors to "overlap" - we were then lying to Windows and saying each monitor was some pixels smaller than it really was, and then adding/subtracting an offset to the cursor position and allowing the cursor to move "less" than it should have done. But windows would still restrict the cursor to have it's "pointing position" within the drawing surface.

Comment: I'm totally fine with extending the drawing surface outside the range of the physical monitors. Does anyone know how to do this? Can I do it directly? or do I need custom graphics drivers?

Comment: I don't _THINK_ you need custom drivers, but I'm not entirely sure. It's been about 8 years since I worked on that stuff.